# Manually keying in a number for list indices in python

Tags: python, list, indices

I have a list of file name
**eg. filenames=['blacklisted.txt', 'abc.txt', 'asfafa.txt', 'heythere.txt']**

I would like to allow the users to manually choose which file name to display , for example ,

*

```
print "Please key in the first log file you would like to use: "
choice1=raw_input()
print"Please key in the second log file you would like to use: "
choice2=raw_input()
filename1=filenames[choice1]
filename2=filenames[choice2]
print filename1
print filename2
```

*

However, i got the error :
    filename1=filenames[choice1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str.

Any advice ? Thanks!

Comment: `choice1=int(raw_input())`, use `int()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first convert the input to int using `int()`

```
print "Please key in the first log file you would like to use: "
choice1=raw_input()
.
.
filename1=filenames[int(choice1)]
.
```

or you could convert the input straight to int

```
choice1 = int(raw_input())
filename1 = filenames[choice1]
```

You should also display the list of files with their corresponding index numbers so the user would know which to choose.

**UPDATE**

For error handling, you can try something like

```
while True:
    choice1 = raw_input('Enter first file name index: ')
    if choice1.strip() != '':
        index1 = int(choice1)
        if index1 >= 0 and index1 < len(filenames):
            filename1 = filenames[index1]
            break // this breaks the while loop when index is correct
```

and the same for choice2

Comment: You probably want to wrap it in a try/except while loop to sanitize input/re-prompt the user.  This can raise a TypeError if the user inputs a value that can't be coerced to an int, or and IndexError if they input a value out of the list's bounds, and you probably don't want the program to crash in those scenarios.

Comment: @SilasRay different checks may be done to avoid errors and index issues, but the answer is meant as a minimal solution to what the OP is asking

Comment: Thanks alot for the help guys! Solved the problem! Will heed your advise and an error handling!